# Applescript or Automator command to .zipx a folder in WinZip Mac

Tags: bash, applescript, automator, winzip

I'm trying to use Hazel automate a process in which I currently manually zip a completed project folder with WinZip Mac into .zipx format, then transfer it to an Archive folder on my NAS. I know there's an archive function built in, but the .zipx format compresses the data more, which is vital for the size of the folders I'm working with.

Hazel can run Applescript, Automator workflow and shell scripts, so I'm hoping at least one of these methods will work.

I've already got a rule set up to move any .zipx files from my project folder to the NAS, I just need to know if there's an easy way to script a command to make WinZip create a .zipx file, using the folder's name as the zip file name (i.e., the folder 20130814 - Project 2 becomes 20130814 - Project 2.zipx. The trigger would be changing the folder's colour to green.

I couldn't find anything specific to WinZip Mac regarding CLI, so I'm not even sure if this is possible, but if so it will save me a lot of repetitive chores!

Anyone have any idea how to set this up?

Comment: As an alternative, you could try to use the 7zip command line utility. It should compress as well as zipx.

Comment: bzip2 also typically has a higher compression ratio than zip or gzip. You can create a bzip2 archive with `COPYFILE_DISABLE= tar -jcf directory.tbz directory`.

Comment: I checked on my Mac.  bzip2 seems to be pre-installed by OS X whereas 7zip must be a third-party addon.

Comment: xz is better than bzip2 or gzip. I only wonder if it is pre-installed on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below script. if you change the variables at the top to suit your needs. this will do the backing up, transferring to the NAS(If it supports SCP) and also clean up afterwards.

I have also added some error checking in incase there is an issue with the tar/scp as you don't want there to be an issue with your backups.

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="/Users/$USER"
archive="/home/backup"
date=$(date +"%d%m%Y")
filename="backup"
NAS="Hostname/IP of NAS"
backup="path to save on NAS"


tar -cvzf $archive/$filename-$date.tgz $directory
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
     echo "success"
else
     echo "error"
     exit 1
fi

#only use the below code if your NAS can use ssh/scp
scp $archive/$filename-$date.tgz $NAS:/$NAS-backup
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    rm $archive/$filename-$date.tgz
else
    echo "error"
    exit 1
fi
```